# How to add chat button or any button that will display on all pages in codeigniter 3 application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

Unable to find root index.html file in codeigniter 3 file structure.
I want to display a chat button that should be visible on all pages.

Which file I have to look for?

The button is displaying on all pages but it sticking just after header, its not relative to body i guess

This is Template.php file which wraps the app-

```
<body style='position:relative,z-index:10'>
 
<?php $this->load->view('website/layout/header'); ?> 
 
<?php $this->load->view('website/layout/whatsapp_button');?>
<?php $this->load->view('website/'.$content);?>
     
</div> 
<?php $this->load->view('website/layout/footer'); ?>
</body>
```

whatsapp_button.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" 
name="viewport" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />


</head>

<body>
 <!-- start header -->
 <div className=''>
      <a style='position:absolute,font-size:20px,z- 
          index:100,top:500px' 
         target='_blank' 
        href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone='>
        Chat
      </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should undo (rollback) this edit, as you are practically asking a brand new question. Ask a new question with the new problem...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such file. Views (your html output) is loaded from a controller

a typical structure in your controllers index function (or wherever you load the html output) could be:

```
$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('content');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

where e.g. header can hold your menu's and footer all the scripts

place your button in one of those, since you will load header and footer always

more: [Loading Codeigniter 3 Pages](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news)